# How to PUT multipart/form-data in PowerShell using Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: api, curl, powershell-3.0

I am trying to transform a cURL command for uploading a zone file in NSONE for Powershell using Invoke-RestMethod.

```
curl -X PUT -F zonefile=@example.com.db -H 'X-NSONE-Key: qACMD09OJXBxT7XOuRs8' https://api.nsone.net/v1/import/zonefile/example.com
```

So far I tried this (based on an answer here by Jeff):

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://api.nsone.net/v1/import/zonefile/example.com -Header @{"X-NSONE-Key" = "qACMD09OJXBxT7XOuRs8"} -Method Put -InFile "c:\example.com.db" -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

But I get this error and have no idea how to fix it.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"Upload a single zone file using multipart/form-data and input name \"zonefile\""}
CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.